A question on Lipschitz domain
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain, which means $\partial \Omega$ can be locally written as the graph of a Lipschitz function. Let $\Omega_\epsilon = \{x \in \Omega\mid d(x, \partial \Omega) > \epsilon\}$. Then will $\partial \Omega_\epsilon$ be Lipschitz when $\epsilon$ is small enough?
